# Why does `write_text` appear to use CRLF and not LF?

Tags: python, windows, text, newline, file-writing

Say, we are on Windows and we want to create a text file with the following content:

```
hello
world
```

We run

```py
from pathlib import Path
Path('my.txt').write_text('hello\nworld')
```

and open the newly create `my.txt` in an editor. I was expecting it to show `LF` since we had `\n` in our string (as opposed to `\r\n`). To my surprise, my editor showed me that `my.txt` had `CRLF`.

Why did it happen? Is there a way to use `write_text` to write `LF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python 3.10 (2021-10-04)](https://www.python.org/downloads/) now supports the `newline` argument. So now you can do:

```py
Path('my.txt').write_text('hello\nworld', newline='\n')
```

Reference:

> `Path.write_text(data, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None)`
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.write_text

Additional reference:

https://bugs.python.org/issue23706

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing Python's [newline mapping feature](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#open) (see `newline` in the linked `open` documentation).

`Path().write_text()` is implemented as follows, so you see you can't set `newline` to `'\n'` or `''`:

```
    def write_text(self, data, encoding=None, errors=None):
        with self.open(mode='w', encoding=encoding, errors=errors) as f:
            return f.write(data)
```

You'll need to set `newline` manually:

```
with Path('my.txt').open('w', newline='\n') as f:
    f.write('hello\nworld')
```

Comment: Is there a way to set it globally to `\n`? (i.e. as if I were on a Linux system)

Comment: The docs say the default is to use `os.linesep`. Maybe setting that to `os.linesep = '\n'` would do the trick?

Comment: (The other option is to open the file as binary, and manually encode whatever text you're going to write there.)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `os.linesep = '\n'` doesn't seem to help. Thank you anyway (+1)